# Outlook 365: Open calendar in new window

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I am using Office 365 Outlook App (not browser) and would like the calendar in a different window then the e-Mails.

There used to be a way to right click on the calendar icon in the left bottom and then have a context menu with "Open in new windows". But no context menu is opening.

What is the way now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. The context menu does not open, when the window is maximized.

You need to make a non-maximized window, open calendar in a new window and then can maximize both again.

Seems to be a bug.

Fixed with 12624

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Outlook 365 desktop client? If so, please make sure you have upgraded your Outlook to the latest version.

According to my tests in my Outlook 365 environment(Version 2001 Build 12430.20050), I can still open the context menu (by using right click) on the calendar icon and choose "Open In New Window" when the window is maximized.

If this is your case, to troubleshoot your issue, please check the following [thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8af8e1fd-5a86-4466-8420-229c87a70da9/outlook-2010-cant-open-calendar-and-contacts-in-new-window?forum=outlook) for more information.

If this is not your case, please provide me with more related information for further research.

Comment: Yes, on my private PC I have the newer version and it actually works. My company seems to use an older version.

Comment: Have you tried the method mentioned before? How is everything going now? If you have any update about this issue, please feel free to post back.

Comment: Yes, today finally the update came and it now works fine.

Comment: It's 2022.  I came here because my option just disappeared for all except the ones in the "All Group Calendars" box.